# Автовоспроизведение звука без действий пользователя

Tags: javascript

Знаю что сейчас большинство браузеров блочит автовоспроизведение. Но вот наткнулся на сервис типа Jivosite и через определённое время у них-же воспроизводиться звук автоматически. Интересует, как же у них это реализовано, или как можно проиграть какое-то аудио без действий пользователя сугубо на JS/JQ

Comment: Возможно на Jivosite все рассчитано на то, что за это определённое время посентитель кликнет, нажмет, в общем обеспечит взаимодействие со страницей, иначе сейчас ни как.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно реализовать посредством обычного HTML

```
<audio autoplay>
<source src="audio/music.ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Этот почти нигде не работает, автоплей уже давно браузеры блочат.

Comment: Странно, только что проверил. В хроме нормально работает

Answer (score 1):

Вариант который отработает в Chrome/Opera/FF , Safari не проверял.

вставить в нужный момент айфреймом, проверять на сайте.

```js
$(function () {

    var time = 5; // через сколько секунд запустить

    setTimeout(function () {
        const audio = 'http://soundbible.com/mp3/ice-cubes-glass-daniel_simon.mp3';
        $('body').append(`<iframe src="${audio}" allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="iframeAudio"> </iframe>`);
    },time*1000)


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```