# Решил добавить фоновую музыку на сайт

Tags: html

Вписал музыку с помощью тега

```
<bgsound src="berserk.mp3" loop="-1" volume="0" balance volume="0"></bgsound>
```

но, при открытии сайта музыка не играет.

Вот код html страницы, тег указан в head

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Главная</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylee.css">
  <bgsound src="anime/berserk.mp3" loop="-1" volume="0" balance volume="0"></bgsound>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="fon">
    <img src="" class="logo">

    <!--   <div id="first">
          <div class="title-text">
          <p>DIMPLESAN</p>
          <h1></h1>
          </div> -->
  </section>

  <section id="osnova">
    <div id="first">
      <div class="title-text">
        <p>Отслеживайте аниме, которые вы смотрели. <br> Сохраняйте, те которые хотите увидеть.</p>
        <h1></h1>
        <div class="osnova-btn">
          <a href="#"><span></span>Присоединиться</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="text-zag">
      <h1>Новинки</h1>
      <br>
      <div class="imgNEW">
        <img class="im1" src="img1.jpg" width="120" height="220">
        <img class="im2" src="img2.jpg" width="120" height="220">
        <img class="im3" src="img3.jpg" width="120" height="220">
        <img class="im4" src="img4.jpg" width="120" height="220">
        <img class="im5" src="img4.jpg" width="120" height="220">
        <img class="im6" src="img4.jpg" width="120" height="220">
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <h1 class="h11"> Продолжение следует </h1>
  </section>
  <section id="footer">
    <div class="footer-obhak">
      <div class="footer-first">
        <h1> Наши проекты </h1>
        <a class="rab1" href="Barber_Shop_img/index.html">Пример 1</a>
        <br>
        <a class="rab12" href="BARBERVLADIKINO/index.html">Пример 2</a>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-second">
        <h1> Обратная связь </h1>
        <p>+7 (925) 436 04 64</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Во-первых, тег bgsound не поддерживается ни одним современным браузером. Во-вторых, все современные браузеры всё равно запрещают сайтам играть звук до тех пор, пока это не разрешит пользователь

Comment: Понятно, тогда можно узнать как можно добавить фон музыку другим способом. Даже если браузер потребует разрешение

Answer (score 0):

Вообще современные браузеры запрещают автовоспроизведение звука, bgsound в html 5 нет на сколько я помню. Можешь попробовать следующее, в перед закрытием head вставь скрипт

```
<script>
   window.onload = function () {
     var context = new AudioContext();
   };
</script>
```

А в конце перед закрытием body это

```
<audio id="audio" loop autoplay>
   <source src="./YOU_AUDIO_FILE.mp3" 
   type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<script>
   let audio = (document.getElementById('audio').autoplay = true);
</script>
```

Но даже в этом случае автоплей не всегда будет срабатывать, всё зависит от настроек браузера.

Comment: Я попробовал с вашим кодом, все получилось, но как и ожидалось музыка работает только в старом explore. Можете подсказать как можно настроить чтобы браузер разрешил воспроизведение, или спрашивал у пользователя разрешение. Не особо представляю  как это реализовать

Comment: Такова политика безопасности современных браузеров. Вот что я нашёл https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140161/538042